# Same Polymorphic Identity for Different Models

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have one model which is the a polymorphic identity of an abstract class

```
class AbstractModel(Base):
    type = Column(String())
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type}

class ModelA(AbstractModel):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "model_a"}

class FlaskModel(ModelA):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "model_a"}
```

I need FlaskModel to to have the same polymorphic relationship as ModelA, because FlaskModel has flask specific restraint that can't exist within ModelA (request context, user permissions, etc)

However, when creating the second class, SQLAlchemy throws a warning about having duplicate, which is for good reason since the any queries always points to the FlaskModel, even if they were queried from ModelA.

Any suggestions on accomplishing this? Splitting the code into a package and then importing isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this route, which worked well and allowed me to create flask specific functions.

```
class AbstractModel(Base):
    type = Column(String())
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type}

class ModelA(AbstractModel):
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "model_a"}

class FlaskModel(ModelA):
    pass

##Event listeners are requireed for the inherited polymorphic relationships
##If additional work needs to be done with different aspect, including after_delete and after_update
##They can als be added here
@event.listens_for(FlaskModel, 'init')
def receive_label_init(target, args, kwargs):
    kwargs["type"] = "model_a"


@event.listens_for(FlaskModel, 'mapper_configured')
def receive_label_mapper_configured(mapper, class_):
    mapper.polymorphic_identity = "model_a"
```